# Tensorflow keras cnn comparison

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

Hi I'm making a report about comparison of cnn s but while creating model should I use weight= None or weight = 'imagenet' which usage will be a better comparison. Here is a sample code.

```
    base_model = VGG16(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), 
include_top = False, 
weights = None)#weights ='imagenet'
```

Comment: We don't have any information about your report, so this question can not be answered properly. Do you know the difference between `weights = None` and `weights = 'imagenet'`?

Comment: Actually its a basic report about their differences of accuracy. Yes I do learnt what imagenet and none changes if i chose imagenet it will bring the pre trained model and if i select none it wont bring any learned thing and I am not sure thought. So I have suspicions about it.

Comment: Yes, The `weights` argument should be one of `None` (random initialization), `imagenet`(pre-training on ImageNet) or the path to the weights file to be loaded. For better understanding you can refer to usage examples of `weights='imagenet'` in image classification models [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models).